# How to capture google maps to image, with angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, jspdf, html2canvas

My english is very poor.
But i try to get the image the google maps and print to pdf.
But i don´t kown, why i don´t capture the image, the response is incomplete.
**The first it´s capture div container.
code TS**

```
htmltoPDF2() {
  html2canvas(document.getElementById('myMaps'),{ useCORS: true}).then( canvas => {
     console.log('canvas', canvas);

     let image64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
     console.log('image64', image64 );

  })

}
```

**html code**

```
<div id="myMaps">
              <div style="min-height: 200px;background-color: aqua;min-width: 100%;">



 <agm-map #map    style="width: 100%;height: 300px;" [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude"
              [zoom]="zoom"
              minZoom="2"
              maxZoom="14"
              [fitBounds]="true"
              >
              <agm-marker [agmFitBounds]="true" [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" ></agm-marker>
            </agm-map>
          </div>
        </div>
```

but the answer it´s an incomplete code 64, if y try to decode it´s a blank image

Comment: Problems stem from using `canvas.toDataURL`. I've had success with https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image instead.

Comment: ```document.getElementById('mymap')``` But your container has the id of ```myMaps```

Comment: To expand on @nullptr.t 's response, you have id=myMaps and element ref #map. You're definitely targeting the wrong element.

Comment: sorry i modifed my code, but this it´s no problem, because i wrtite worng the code, the response it´s data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgICAgMCAgIDAwMDBAYEBAQEBAgGBgUGCQgKCgkICQkKDA8MCgsOCwkJDRENDg8QEBEQCgwSExIQEw8QEBD/2wBDAQMDAwQDBAgEBAgQCwkLEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBD/wAARCADwAgoDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAFQABAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAn/xAAUEAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/8QAFAEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/EABQRAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AKpgAAAAAAA

Comment: To expand on @nullptr.t 's response, you have id=myMaps and element ref #map. You're definitely targeting the wrong element, **I don´t understant**